# In Jonah 2:6, what does he mean by 'roots/cuttings/forms of the mountains' and 'about me forever'' when it was only for 3 days?

Tags: jonah

> Jonah 2
>   6 I descended to the **roots of the mountains**. ***The earth with its bars was around me forever***, But You have brought up my life from the pit, O LORD my God.`New American Standard Bible`.

.

> Jonah 2
>   6 To the **cuttings of mountains** I have come down, The earth, her bars are behind me to the age. And Thou bringest up from the pit my life, O Jehovah my God. `Young's Literal Translation`

What kind of 'roots or cuttings' are written in Jonah 2, and why 'forever' when he was 'away' for only 3 days?

Answer (score 1):

The *JPS Tanakh* suggests "base of the mountains" as a translation for the phrase you indicate.

The unvocalized Hebrew is קצב (*qṣb*), which the Masoretic Text interpolates as קֶ֫צֶב (*qě·ṣěḇ*), meaning "shape" or "foundation" (*Dictionary of Biblical Languages with Semantic Domains*) - consistent with the *Tanakh* translation and the YLT version you quote.

An alternate interpolation would be קָצַב (*qā·ṣǎḇ*), which according to the same source means to "cut off", but this is not, I think, what is actually in the Masoretic Text.

Interestingly, the Greek Septuagint version of this passage (which is older than the Masoretic Text) reads:

> εἰς σχισμὰς ὀρέων, κατέβην εἰς γῆν ἧς οἱ μοχλοὶ αὐτῆς κάτοχοι αἰώνιοι·
>   καὶ ἀναβήτω φθορὰ ζωῆς μου, Κύριε ὁ θεός μου
>
> *To the clefts of the mountains; I went down into the earth, whose bars are the everlasting barriers: yet, O Lord my God, let my ruined
>   life be restored.*

(Brenton's English translation) which seems to agree more with *qā·ṣǎḇ* than with *qě·ṣěḇ*.

If I had to guess, I would say that the NASB translators observed the discrepancy between the Masoretic Text and the Septuagint, looked for a basis for the Septuagint translation, and concluded that קָצַב was more faithful to the original Hebrew than what was chosen in the Masoretic Text.

There are quite a few very sharp Hebrew scholars on this site, so I am sure that if my conclusion is weak they will be all over this answer soon.

As for why Jonah says "forever", I assume it was because at the point that he was praying what is in the Bible text, he did not know when or even if he would be released.